# Running Unit Tests in Isolation in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest, vstest

When I run unit tests in Visual Studio 2017, are they run in isolation and if not, how can I enable it?

With vstest.console.exe I can enable isolation with /InIsolation and I'd like to know how to control this in Visual Studio.